# How to properly pass values to an event handler function of any widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm experiencing an issue with a list view. I'd like my ListView Items to provide buttons to perform an action on individual items. But the event handler I'm passing to them is unexpectedly and repeatedly called. 
However, I'd expect it to be called only when the child's button is called.
What have I done wrong?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:horaires_ratp/model/Database.dart';

class StationsList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _StationsListState();
  }
}

class _StationsListState extends State<StationsList> {
  List<Station> _stations = List<Station>();


  _StationsListState() {
    Station().select().toList().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _stations = value;
      });
    });
  }

  void _handleStationDelete(Station station){
    //station.delete(true);
    print("called");
    Station().select().toList().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _stations = value;
      });
    });

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _stations.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return StationComponent(_stations[index], _handleStationDelete);
            }));
  }
}

class StationComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  final Station _station;
  final Function _handleDelete;

  StationComponent( this._station,  this._handleDelete);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(_station.name, textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed: _handleDelete(_station))
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[Row(children: <Widget>[])],
                )
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass functions like this

```
onPressed: onPressFunction
```

if it needs some value then

```
onPressed: () => onPressFunction(value)
```

**and not like**

```
onPressed: onPressFunction(value)
```

---

so your code should be

```
IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed:() => _handleDelete(_station))
```